# Getting The box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found on firing 'vagrant up' from terminal in ubuntu

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I have installed Vagrant and once I am inside my project folder from the terminal I fire the following commands:

1. `vagrant box add hashicorp/precise32 http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box`

Output:

```
[vagrant] Downloading with Vagrant::Downloaders::HTTP... 
[vagrant] Downloading box: files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box 
[vagrant] Downloading box: hashicorp-files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box 
[vagrant] Extracting box... 
[vagrant] Verifying box... 
[vagrant] Cleaning up downloaded box...
```

2. `vagrant init hashicorp/precise32`

Output: `A Vagrantfile has been placed in this directory`

3. `vagrant up`

I get an error that says:

```
The box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found
```

Comment: Did each of the commands actually succeed?

Comment: The first command was successful and the terminal showed [vagrant] Downloading with Vagrant::Downloaders::HTTP...
[vagrant] Downloading box: http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box
[vagrant] Downloading box: http://hashicorp-files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box
[vagrant] Extracting box...
[vagrant] Verifying box...
[vagrant] Cleaning up downloaded box...  The second command was also successful and said that A `Vagrantfile` has been placed in this directory. You are now ready to `vagrant up` your first virtual environment. I get the error after the third step.

Comment: Please run again with an updated version of vagrant with 'vagrant up --debug'. Might be fixed through [#5016](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5016) and [#5231](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/5231)

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is edit you vagrant file and define the vm.box_url and vm.box options like this.

config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/precise32.box"

config.vm.box = "precise32"

and then run "**vagrant up**"

Answer (score 1):

Please, install Vagrant from .deb package which is downloaded from original site http://www.vagrantup.com/downloads

Comment: Is this based on any insight into the problem, or just a "turn it off and turn it on again" suggestion?