# Vagrant on Ubuntu: can't find any boxes

Tags: ubuntu, vagrant

I am trying to use `vagrant` on Ubuntu.

I just tried to init vagrant like documented here (https://vagrantcloud.com/ubuntu/boxes/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-core-edge-amd64):

```
vagrant init ubuntu/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-core-edge-amd64
vagrant up --provider virtualbox
```

I always get the error message:

```
* The box 'ubuntu/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-core-edge-amd64' could not be found.
```

Same error with any other boxes.

Referring to this question: [Getting The box 'hashicorp/precise32' could not be found on firing 'vagrant up' from terminal in ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28340781/getting-the-box-hashicorp-precise32-could-not-be-found-on-firing-vagrant-up), I need to edit my Vagrantfile and enter the url of the box.

But I tried URLs like

```
config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-core-edge-amd64"
```

and

```
config.vm.box_url = "http://files.vagrantup.com/ubuntu/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-core-edge-amd64"
```

I always get a http 404 not found error. I just need the correct URL, maybe I need to do more than this...

Comment: Are you able to add the box manually `vagrant box add ubuntu/ubuntu-15.04-snappy-core-edge-amd64`?

Comment: Usage: vagrant box add <name> <url> [--provider provider] [-h]

Comment: The usage of `vagrant box add` changed in v1.5, what version of vagrant are you using?

Comment: Oh, that's it. 1.4.3 is installed, I might need to add another PPA for vagrant 1.5 or install from source

Answer (score 2):

The vagrant version installed using

```
apt-get install vagrant
```

was 1.4.3, but 1.5 or later was required.

The quickest way to install the latest version is:
Downloading the Debian Version (32bit or 64bit) from
https://www.vagrantup.com/downloads.html